# How is the concurrency query performance of elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does elasticsearch can handle concurrency search/aggregation well? (For example, 1000 people issue the same/different query at the same time)

Please note that I am not talking about concurrency update, only search/agg.

Databases like oracle/mysql all talking about concurrency in there docs. Did not find elasticsearch talking about this. Does that mean concurrency is not a problem to the data structure and architecture of elasticsearch?

I know cache of filter is one good thing to make concurrency query easier. Anything else?

Comment: It's a distributed database and it scales horizontally. You can always add more nodes to handle increasing concurrent searches.

Comment: You can't rely on scale alone.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/finite-scale.html

Comment: @AssHat_ True, but in order for the state to be a bottle-neck, you would need hundreds or even thousands of nodes, or a terrible design with dynamic fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queries can be cached for re-use with minimal overhead.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html#filter-caching

This allows faster processing of future queries over the same data.

The cluster configuration and data allocation will also have an impact on performance. Requests should be made in a round-robin fashion, If a single node is receives 1000 requests simultaneously its performance will be degraded vs dividing the work among multiple nodes.

Mappings and analyzers can also have significant influence on performance.

[Queries that require retrieval and parsing of the _source field are expensive.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html)

[Using Query-time synonym translation will be expensive.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html)

**The reality is the performance is based on the particular application.**